# Unity - How can I make a button do one event at a time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, button

I am attempting to have an assembly of objects move one at a time when a button is pressed. I have managed to get the animations to work, now I am wondering what the best way is to make each event happen one at a time, rather than all at once.

[image]

I tried to use scripts instead with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Animator Behaviour Tree and make a Default Status(animation) so that each animation is played, it goes back to Default State.
For choosing the animation you want to play, try adding conditions on your script(ex. when animation1 is done playing, set animation2 next so it can be played when the button is pressed.)